# Aligning both tikz pictures and their captions

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I am using two tikz pictures in subfigures. The baseline parameter allows aliging the subfigures via the nodes, however the caption (b) is much above the caption (a) in such case. If I don't you baseline, then the caption are aligned, but not the figures. Is that possible to match the alignment for both simultaneously?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \subfigure[First SS]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b),->,>=stealth',shorten <= 2pt, shorten >= 2pt,auto,node distance= 2.2cm]

  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw,circle split,minimum width={2em}]

    \node[state]    (a1)                                            {$a_1$ \nodepart{lower} $A$};
    \node[state]    (b)     [below right = .3cm and 3.5cm of a1]    {$b$ \nodepart{lower} $B$};
    \node[state]    (a2)    [below left = .3cm and 3.5cm of b]     {$a_2$ \nodepart{lower} $A$};

    \path[->]
        (a1)    edge [loop above, below left]   node    {$\frac13\;$}   (a1)
                edge [bend left]                node    {$\frac13$}     (b)
                edge [bend right,left]          node    {$\frac13$}     (a2)
        (a2)    edge [bend right, right]        node    {$\frac23$}     (a1)
                edge [bend right, below]        node    {$\frac13$}     (b)
        (b)    edge [loop above, below right]  node    {$\;\;1$}       (b)
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:ss.example.a}
  }
  \qquad
  \subfigure[Second SS]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(-b),->,>=stealth',shorten <= 2pt, shorten >= 2pt,auto,node distance= 2.2cm]

  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw,circle split,minimum width={2em}]

    \node[state]    (-a)                        {$\bar a$ \nodepart{lower} $A$};
    \node[state]    (-b) [right = 3cm of -a]    {$\bar b$ \nodepart{lower} $B$};

    \path[->]
        (-a) edge [loop above, below left]   node    {$\frac23\;$}   (-a)
            edge                 node    {$\frac13$}     (-b)
        (-b) edge [loop above, below right]  node    {$\;\;1$} (-b)
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:ss.example.b}
  }
  \caption{Example of two finite autonomous SSs.}
  \label{fig:ss.example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to measure the bigger picture.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox{\bigpicture}
\newcommand{\adapttobigpicture}{%
  \vrule height\ht\bigpicture depth\dp\bigpicture width0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\sbox{\bigpicture}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b),->,>=stealth',shorten <= 2pt, shorten >= 2pt,auto,node distance= 2.2cm]

  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw,circle split,minimum width={2em}]

    \node[state]    (a1)                                            {$a_1$ \nodepart{lower} $A$};
    \node[state]    (b)     [below right = .3cm and 3.5cm of a1]    {$b$ \nodepart{lower} $B$};
    \node[state]    (a2)    [below left = .3cm and 3.5cm of b]     {$a_2$ \nodepart{lower} $A$};

    \path[->]
        (a1)    edge [loop above, below left]   node    {$\frac13\;$}   (a1)
                edge [bend left]                node    {$\frac13$}     (b)
                edge [bend right,left]          node    {$\frac13$}     (a2)
        (a2)    edge [bend right, right]        node    {$\frac23$}     (a1)
                edge [bend right, below]        node    {$\frac13$}     (b)
        (b)    edge [loop above, below right]  node    {$\;\;1$}       (b)
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
  \subfloat[First SS]{\usebox{\bigpicture}\label{fig:ss.example.a}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Second SS]{%
  \adapttobigpicture
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(-b),->,>=stealth',shorten <= 2pt, shorten >= 2pt,auto,node distance= 2.2cm]

  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw,circle split,minimum width={2em}]

    \node[state]    (-a)                        {$\bar a$ \nodepart{lower} $A$};
    \node[state]    (-b) [right = 3cm of -a]    {$\bar b$ \nodepart{lower} $B$};

    \path[->]
        (-a) edge [loop above, below left]   node    {$\frac23\;$}   (-a)
            edge                 node    {$\frac13$}     (-b)
        (-b) edge [loop above, below right]  node    {$\;\;1$} (-b)
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \label{fig:ss.example.b}%
  }
  \caption{Example of two finite autonomous SSs.}
  \label{fig:ss.example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please, note that `subfigure` has been obsolete and deprecated for several years. Either use `subfig` as I did here (changing `\subfigure` to `\subfloat`) or `subcaption`.

In `\sbox{\bigpicture}{...}` you save the bigger picture (not necessarily the first one), and use `\adapttobigpicture` in the smaller one. The `\sbox{\bigpicture}{...}` part must go before using `\adapttobigpicture`, better as the first object in the `figure` environment. If you have more than one row of subfigures, you can reuse the save box at the start of each row.

[image]